# How To Reference External Classes in Fitnesse

Tags: java, fitnesse, functional-testing

I have two jar files.

- MyProduct.jar (The business logic)
- MyProductFixture.jar. (The fixture that calls the bl)

The MyProductFixture.jar has a dependency on MyProduct.jar.

When I try to run fitnesse calling the fixture in MyProductFixture, I get a ClassNotFoundException for a class in MyProduct.jar.

Attempting to set the -classpath java parameter on the command line fails because the -jar command ignores the -classpath parameter.

How can I resolve the external dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Fitnesse page I had to add two classpath references.

First to the fixture. (Obvious), the second to the external dependency. The key is the *

```
!path /path/to/MyProductFixture.jar
!path /path/to/my/product/*
```

Notice the following does **NOT** work.

```
!path /path/to/MyProduct.jar
```